# texImage2D in webgl with Texture of type FLOAT and RED format, do work only with internal format of R16F

Tags: textures, webgl2

In WEBGL2, I'm trying to fill a TEXTURE_2D with Float32Array. Everything went well until i change my type to FLOAT, RED and R32F. The combination is legit but this only work with FLOAT, RED and R16F.
I'm under the lastest chrome 114.0.5735.110 (Build officiel) (64 bits).

```
function glCheckError(gl, mess) {
    const error = gl.getError();
    if (error !== gl.NO_ERROR) {
        console.error(`Webgl error in ${mess} : ${error}`);
    }
}

function createTexture(gl, internalFormat, width, height, format, type, data) {
    const texture = gl.createTexture();

    // tell webgl to invert texture coordinate in Y
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, type, data);
    glCheckError(gl, "texImage2D");
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

    return texture;
}
```

then this work

```
   const altitudes = createTexture(gl, gl.R16F, 256, 256, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, elevationData);
```

and this NOT work

```
   const altitudes = createTexture(gl, gl.R32F, 256, 256, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, elevationData);
```

elevation data is a valid Float32Array.

Anybody has an explanation ??